# Keep receiving assighment to itself, and missing method body errors

Tags: java, methods, subclass

I have been working on this assignment for a few days now and I can't figure this problem out. The assignment is as follows.

Design and implement a class representing a Person along with 3 subclasses using the following guidelines:

a.Create a class named Person and its three subclasses named Employee, Student, Retired.

b.The Person has the following data fields: name, year_of_birth, isStudying, and isEmployed. It also has methods for setting and getting the values of each of the fields along with a method to calculate the current age and display the status of a Person. A constructor that sets the isStudying and isEmployed fields to false is also included in the Person class. You are welcome to add additional data fields and methods if you like.

c.For your Person, Employee, Student and Retired classes the getStatus method returns the values shown in the table below based on the current values of the attributes:

1.Finally, create a Java test class that simulates using your Person class. In your test class you should at a minimum: a) Construct 4 instances of a Person, b) print the names of your instances c) print the status of your instances based on the values of their age, isStudying and isEmployed attributes.

The following code is actually in 5 different files in the same project.

First file:

```
public class Person2 {//begin class
    //declare variables
    String name;
    int year_of_birth;
    boolean isStudying;
    boolean isEmployed;
    int age;

public Person2(boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying){//begin constructor
    this.isEmployed = false;
    this.isStudying = false;
}//end constructor

public int getYear(){//get year method
        return year_of_birth;
}//end method

public String getName(){//get name method
        return name;
}//end method

public boolean getEmployed(){//get employed method
        return isEmployed;
}//end method

public boolean getStudying(){//get employed method
        return isStudying;
    }//end method

public int getAge(int year_of_birth){//get year method
        age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    return age;
}//end method

public int getStatus(int age);{//begin method
    this.age = age;
    if (age < 30 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false || true){
        System.out.println(name + " is a student");
    }    else if(age > 30 || age < 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false || true){
            System.out.println(name + " is an employee");
            }    else if(age > 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false){
                    System.out.println(name + " is retired");
            }
}//end method

public void setName(String name){//set name method
        this.name = name;
}//end method

public void setYear (int year){//set year method
        this.year_of_birth = year;
}//end method

public void setEmployed(boolean employed){//set employed method
        this.isEmployed = employed;
}//end method

public void setAge (){//set year method
        this.age = age;
}//end method

public static void main(String[] args) {
        }

}//end class
```

Second file:

```
class Student extends Person2 {//begin class

    public Student(boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying, int age) {//begin constructer
    super(isEmployed, isStudying);
    this.isEmployed = false;
    this.isStudying = true;
    }//end constructer          
}//end class
```

Third file:

```
class Retired extends Person2 {
    public Retired(boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying) {//begin constructer
        super(isEmployed, isStudying);
        this.isEmployed = false;
        this.isStudying = false;
    }//end constructer        
}//end class
```

Forth File:

```
class Employee extends Person2 {
    public Employee(boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying) {//begin constructer
        super(isEmployed, isStudying);
        this.isEmployed = true;
        this.isStudying = false;
    }//end constructer  
}//end class
```

Fifth File:

```
public class PersonTest {//begin class
    public static void main(String[] args) {//begin main
    Person2 user1 = new Person2(false, true);
    user1.setName("John Doe");
    user1.setYear(1986);
    System.out.println("The clients name is " + user1.getName() + ".");
    System.out.println("The client is " + user1.getAge(1986) + ".");
    user1.getStatus(age); 
    //new user
    Person2 user2 = new Person2(true, false);
    user2.setName("Mary Joe");
    user2.setYear(1975);
    System.out.println("The clients name is " + user2.getName() + ".");
    System.out.println("The client is " + user2.getAge(1975) + ".");
    user2.getStatus(age);
    //new user
    Person2 user3 = new Person2(true, false);
    user3.setName("Forrest Burtner");
    user3.setYear(1924);
    System.out.println("The clients name is " + user3.getName() + ".");
    System.out.println("The client is " + user3.getAge(1924) + ".");
    user3.getStatus(age);
    //new user
    Person2 user4 = new Person2(false, false);
    user4.setName("John Connor");
    user4.setYear(1910);
    System.out.println("The clients name is " + user4.getName() + ".");
    System.out.println("The client is " + user4.getAge(1910) + ".");
    user3.getStatus(age);
    }//end main     
}//end class
```

All my problems seem to stem for the getStatus method, not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My problem is I receive assignment to itself error and missing method body error in the getStatus method:

Comment: **public int getStatus(int age);{//begin method**
    **this.age = age;**
    if (age < 30 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false || true){
        System.out.println(name + " is a student");
    }    else if(age > 30 || age < 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false || true){
            System.out.println(name + " is an employee");
            }    else if(age > 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false){
                    System.out.println(name + " is retired");
            }
}//end method

Comment: Where is 'age' assigned a value in PersonTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in **Person2** class as in your method contains a typo `public String getStatus(int age);` i.e **semi-colon** at the end, I don't know how the compiler treated this usually it is treated as an *empty statement* and as you are returning the status which is usually String so changed the type of the method from int to string and in `PersonTest` class got the age of the user and called the `getStatus()` with the age and displayed the result.

```
public String getStatus(int age){
    this.age = age;
    if (age < 30 && isStudying == true && isEmployed == false){
        return name + " is a student";
    }    else if((age > 30 || age < 65) && isStudying == false && isEmployed == true){
        return name + " is an employee";
    }    else if(age > 65 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false){
        return name + " is retired";
    }
    return null;
}
```

The **PersonTest**  class

```
public class PersonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person2 user1 = new Person2(false, true);
        user1.setName("John Doe");
        user1.setYear(1986);
        System.out.println("The clients name is " + user1.getName() + ".");
        System.out.println("The client is " + user1.getAge(1986) + ".");
        System.out.println(user1.getStatus(user1.getAge(1986)));

        Person2 user2 = new Person2(true, false);
        user2.setName("Mary Joe");
        user2.setYear(1975);
        System.out.println("The clients name is " + user2.getName() + ".");
        System.out.println("The client is " + user2.getAge(1975) + ".");
        System.out.println(user2.getStatus(user2.getAge(1975)));

        Person2 user3 = new Person2(false, false);
        user3.setName("Forrest Burtner");
        user3.setYear(1924);
        System.out.println("The clients name is " + user3.getName() + ".");
        System.out.println("The client is " + user3.getAge(1924) + ".");
        System.out.println(user3.getStatus(user3.getAge(1924)));

        Person2 user4 = new Person2(false, false);
        user4.setName("John Connor");
        user4.setYear(1910);
        System.out.println("The clients name is " + user4.getName() + ".");
        System.out.println("The client is " + user4.getAge(1910) + ".");
        System.out.println(user3.getStatus(user4.getAge(1910)));
    }
}
```

Everything will work

Comment: give a sec i'm updating it

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem. Somehow  still get an error under my setAge method in Person2 class. Same thing "assignment to itself". What causes this error.

Comment: public void setAge (int age){
        this.age = age;
    } this should work

Comment: If it fixed the problem you can accept this as you answer and vote it up

Comment: Thanks fixed it right up. Tried to vote it up, my reputation isn't high enough yet

Comment: One more question my output keeps getting "is something else" for my first two instance (i.e. John Doe, and Mary Joe). It looks to me like all the parameters add up to be a student for john doe, and an employee for mary joe.

Comment: All the parameter add up to be student for john doe and employee for mary joe but it keeps showing "is something else for status.

Comment: Updated getStatus() avove moreover do this public Person2(boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying){
        this.isEmployed = isEmployed;
        this.isStudying = isStudying;
    }  and Person2 user3 = new Person2(false, false); because age>65 so isEmployeed cannot be true according to your implementation

Answer (score 0):

This line and the others like it are probably the problem:

```
if (age < 30 && isStudying == false && isEmployed == false || true)
```

That condition will always be true, because it evaluates like this:

```
if (   (   (age < 30)
           &&
           (isStudying == false)
           &&
           (isEmployed == false)
       )
       ||
       true
   )
```

I don't know what you were trying to represent with the `|| true` at the end, but it's likely to be a problem.

Some other notes:

- Don't use `==` with booleans. Instead, just use the boolean, and if you're looking for a negative use `!`. So `isStudying` if they're studying, and `!isStudying` if they aren't.
- `< 30` and `> 30` are not the only possibilities. Someone can also **be** 30. You probably wanted `< 30` and `>= 30` as conditions (and similarly for `65`).
- There shouldn't be a `;` after `public int getStatus(int age)` before the opening `{`

Side note: The assignment is really weird. You wouldn't have an instance of a `Student` class and set it up so that `getStatus` said they were retired. That just doesn't make any sense.

You didn't show the table, but here's a version that says:

- A student is someone who is under 30, studying, and not employed
- An employee is someone who is at least 30, not studying, and employed (note that we don't care that they may be 65 or older)
- A retired person is someone who is at least 65, not studying, and not employed
- Otherwise, they're something else (as I'm fairly sure we can fail to match all three of those)

In code:

```
public int getStatus(int age) { //begin method
    this.age = age;
    if (age < 30 && isStudying && !isEmployed) {
        System.out.println(name + " is a student");
    } else if (age >= 30 && !isStudying && isEmployed) {
        System.out.println(name + " is an employee");
    } else if (age >= 65 && !isStudying && !isEmployed) {
        System.out.println(name + " is retired");
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " is something else");
    }
} //end method
```

This is indended as an *example* of how you might approach that function. You will have to apply the rules in the assignment yourself.

Comment: sir try to analyze the problem before giving a solution I dont think `public int getStatus(int age);` will compile any way and for some silly mistake downvoting is not a genius thing

Comment: Thanks for the insight, the if statement does look a little cleaner. The reason I did greater than 30 and less than 65 is cause that how it reads in the table. I could post the table here , it would paste properly.

Comment: @M.Sharma: Indeed, there's an extra `;` there. Re voting: If you make assumptions about who voted on your question/answer based on who people are *commenting* on it, you will be wrong much, much more often than right. And even when right, complaining about it is pointless.

Comment: Yeah that definitely fixed the problem, but the assignment said I had to create a constructor in the Person2 class that sets them both as false. However, I think I am at a point that I can figure this out. I appreciate all your help I voted this up.